# Using Facebook API to get user mail with javascript and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, email, response

I'm making an application and I'm giving the user the chance to use Facebook as Log In.

So at the moment I only need to GET the user Mail from Facebook, therefore I use make a GET to a Fb link that looks like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/123456789?access_token=xxxxxxxx&fields=email
```

I use this in Postman and get the next response:

```
{ "email": "iwadgpp_greeneberg_1453348688@tfbnw.net", "id": "123456789"}
```

So that seems to work, but in Node, I'm using request to get the same info and use it but it is not returning the same info it returns some thrash i don't understand haha. So here's the node code...

```
var mail;

    request.get(route).on('response', function(response) {
      mail = response.email;
      console.log(" Response:  " + JSON.stringify(response)); //see below for log *
      console.log("Value mail " + mail); // prints undefined
    });
```

- And this is what my response logs:

> ```
> {
>     "statusCode": 200,
>     "headers": {
>         "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
>         "etag": "\"75b67769eea5f8b638d51e10acd6ac956ea02ebc\"",
>         "pragma": "no-cache",
>         "cache-control": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
>         "facebook-api-version": "v2.5",
>         "expires": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT",
>         "content-type": "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8",
>         "x-fb-trace-id": "BaLgwkX/DEi",
>         "x-fb-rev": "2470441",
>         "x-fb-debug": "biKg3fXqIkPc1427FmOQYL8Psme8gSRwvza6ouWMpJUyb1x6uCfRaupgmcW6eMkgydC2fQc2XmyIprO1KetWrQ==",
>         "date": "Thu, 28 Jul 2016 00:10:11 GMT",
>         "connection": "close",
>         "content-length": "79"
>     },
>     "request": {
>         "uri": {
>             "protocol": "https:",
>             "slashes": true,
>             "auth": null,
>             "host": "graph.facebook.com",
>             "port": 443,
>             "hostname": "graph.facebook.com",
>             "hash": null,
>             "search": "?access_token=EAAB8mladZBAABAMiuuCkcCcqp9MEw51E7UTszuMkXzaqUmMgRDXFxW7zkqtOU4UTu5taPZBNA6TNah9ZBK5y7Xp4qG6tkMnEy9ZCevx6mS8ZCe39HcVPFF3dWaPS1FsCnIuNmkSe9o90R93IZBpuX3OAZCI9B8uVl7SQCsyYfCnG4czUrZCFFt9x&fields=email",
>             "query": "access_token=EAAB8mladZBAABAMiuuCkcCcqp9MEw51E7UTszuMkXzaqUmMgRDXFxW7zkqtOU4UTu5taPZBNA6TNah9ZBK5y7Xp4qG6tkMnEy9ZCevx6mS8ZCe39HcVPFF3dWaPS1FsCnIuNmkSe9o90R93IZBpuX3OAZCI9B8uVl7SQCsyYfCnG4czUrZCFFt9x&fields=email",
>             "pathname": "/108142206235544",
>             "path": "/108142206235544?access_token=EAAB8mladZBAABAMiuuCkcCcqp9MEw51E7UTszuMkXzaqUmMgRDXFxW7zkqtOU4UTu5taPZBNA6TNah9ZBK5y7Xp4qG6tkMnEy9ZCevx6mS8ZCe39HcVPFF3dWaPS1FsCnIuNmkSe9o90R93IZBpuX3OAZCI9B8uVl7SQCsyYfCnG4czUrZCFFt9x&fields=email",
>             "href": "https://graph.facebook.com/108142206235544?access_token=EAAB8mladZBAABAMiuuCkcCcqp9MEw51E7UTszuMkXzaqUmMgRDXFxW7zkqtOU4UTu5taPZBNA6TNah9ZBK5y7Xp4qG6tkMnEy9ZCevx6mS8ZCe39HcVPFF3dWaPS1FsCnIuNmkSe9o90R93IZBpuX3OAZCI9B8uVl7SQCsyYfCnG4czUrZCFFt9x&fields=email"
>         },
>         "method": "GET",
>         "headers": {}
>     }
> }
> ```

This are test accounts so I don't really mind. But yeah, I'm sending right (testing) values which work in Postman but not in Node. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Did the test user grant email permission to the app?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yes. This are the test users Facebook adds by default.

Comment: Facebook doesn't automatically grant any permission to your app for test users. Debug the access token and I bet you will see it hasn't granted email permission

Comment: Realized what my problem is, I'm not telling Facebook which application I'm. Still I'm not sure where I've to add my app ID and my app secret.